# how to display images form a folder inside another folder laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, directory, prettyphoto

I am trying to display images from a database through folder. I have a folder. Albums, and inside that more folders ("home", "school"). I'm saving images into "Album/home/a.jpg". I want to display images from folder ../home.. (eg: Album/home/a.jpg)

I used this code:

```
<a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gallery]" class="thumbnail" href="{{URL::asset('/Albums/'.$gallery->galimg)}}" width="100%" height="100%" >
<img src="{{URL::asset('/Albums/'.$gallery->galimg)}}" width="100%" height="100%"/> </a>
```

but it's not working `{{URL::asset('/Albums/'.$gallery->galimg)}}` only see gallery place (one square) not image..

how to solve it??

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over.

Comment: sorry.........Ok..can you please give me the answer anyone.........

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to take care of few things.

1. Make sure that the folder `Albums` is located inside the `public` folder directly if not reference it.
2. Check the database whether you are storing just `image name` or `full path` or may be there is no `extension` of images on db.
3. No need to use URL facade. There is asset method which you can use directly ( specific in Laravel4.* ) like this `{{ asset($gallery->image) }}`